# 500 Internal Server Error - handler, asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, handler

I am using a simple handler to display an image on MVC view, it works great on my localhost but when I publish it to our hosting server I get this error (using Fiddler):

```
GET ImageHandler.ashx?img=b...w=255&level=128&slice=0  500 Internal Server Error
```

Here is the view script:

```
<img id="Image1" alt="image"  src="ImageHandler.ashx?img=bmptest.bmp&window=255&level=128&slice=0" height="512" width="512" />
```

Here is the handler's script:

```
   public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string sImageFileName = "";
            int slice = 0;
            int window = 0;
            int level = 0;
            sImageFileName = context.Request.QueryString["img"].ToLower().Trim();
           .....
            System.Drawing.Image objImage = null;
            Image bmp = Image.FromFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("content/" + sImageFileName));
            MemoryStream objMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            bmp.Save(objMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] imageContent = new byte[objMemoryStream.Length];
            objMemoryStream.Position = 0;
            objMemoryStream.Read(imageContent, 0, (int)objMemoryStream.Length);
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageContent);
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I modified web.cong by adding:

```
<system.web>
......
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.ashx" type="DirectshowTest.ImageHandler,DirectshowTest"/>
    </httpHandlers>
   </system.web>
```

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Are there any details in the event log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to Global.asax:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");
```

It is working now.